# Porquê o NodeJS tem versões 4.x, 5.x, 6.x e 0.1x.x, etc

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Porquê o Node.js existe nas versões 4, 5 e 6, mas também existe nas versões `0.x.x`. Ou talvez, quais as diferenças entre as versões `x.x` e `0.x.x`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Há dois aspetos a referir em resposta à tua pergunta.

- porquê o salto de `0.x.x` para `4.x.x`
- porquê versões 4, 5 e 6 quase simultâneas

O Node.js quando foi lançado reuniu muitos dos craques de programação da altura. Como muitas tecnologias experimentais/novas havia muitos caminhos possíveis e pessoas com ideias diferentes. A comunidade não consegui entender-se e dois modelos de "governação" eram desejados:

> *"open governance model" as opposed to corporate stewardship*

Ou seja, um grupo mais formal com regras rígidas e outro com mais espirito cooperativo e mais flexível. Isto levou a uma ruptura e nasceu a comunidade **io.js**.

A nova comunidade, mais flexivel desenvolveu-se mais rápido e lançou versões próprias do Node.js (io.js).

Passado algum tempo ambas as comunidades amadureceram e voltaram a olhar uma para a outra e a identificar mais valias na unificação. E assim aconteceu, em 
2015 a comunidade bem ativa da fork io.js voltou a juntar-se à comunidade Node.js, consciente das vantagens da re-união.

Isto gerou alguns desafios ao versionamento e ficou decidido que as versões `io.js` teriam numeros próprios, [então as versões ficaram assim](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/):

> **Node antigo:** versões **0.1.x** a **0.12.x**
>   **io.js**: versões **1.x.x** a **3.x.x**
>   **Node reunificado:** versões **4.x.x** em diante

#### Como funciona o versionamento em Node?

As versões do Node são *LTS** intercaladas, ou seja as versões pares são estáveis e as versões ímpares são instáveis, experimentais e de desenvolvimento.

As versões `0.4` e `0.10` foram as mais usadas talvez, e estáveis. Hoje em dia é possivel fazer download das versões `4.x.x` e `6.x.x`. A versão `5.x.x` não está disponivel [na página principal](https://nodejs.org/en/) para não enganar quem não sabe isto. A versão `4.x.x` recebeu um suporte inicial de 30 meses, enquanto a versão `5.x.x` recebeu um suporte somente de 8 meses, mais ou menos até ao lançamento da versão estável `6.0.0`

---

**Notas:**

> **LTS** - long term support (suporte longo)