# Qual a diferença entre a versão 8 e a versão 6 do NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Eu comecei recentemente a estudar NodeJS em sua versão v6.11.3 e após uma confusão entre as documentações do site oficial, eu descobri que o NodeJS possui outra versão disponível, a 8.6. Eu fiquei bem confuso quando vi isso, e queria saber o motivo da existência das duas versões, quais são suas diferenças, qual possui o melhor desempenho, etc.

Comment: Não há motivos para separação, assim como todo programa, sempre recebe atualização.

Comment: Veja essa pergunta aqui no SOpt, [Como definir a versão de um software?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101896/como-definir-a-vers%C3%A3o-de-um-software)

Comment: Não entendi sua comparação.

Comment: Quis dizer, que um programa sempre recebe melhorias é porque isso que existe versões diferentes. o link da pergunta que passei te explica como funciona o versionamento.

Comment: Certo, mas a questão do node é que elas existem simultaneamente, e recebem atualizações separadas, como se fossem 2 projetos diferentes. Eu só quero saber porque acontece isso e a diferença das versões.

Comment: Essa pergunta já foi feita aqui [Porquê o NodeJS tem versões 4.x, 5.x, 6.x e 0.1x.x, etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127660/porqu%C3%AA-o-nodejs-tem-vers%C3%B5es-4-x-5-x-6-x-e-0-1x-x-etc)

Comment: Obrigado, já tinha procurado mas sem sucesso.